# malformed database schema - SQLite with LinqPad

Tags: sqlite, schema, linqpad, malformed

This one has me stumped - it worked perfectly on Friday;  No system changes except for a windows update.
Today, I am connecting to the same sqlite database and am getting this error.
database disk image is malformed
malformed database schema (vSalesTerritory) - near "(": syntax error

I also connected to the database using DBeaver, which continues to work without complaint.

The cause is that the view definition is

```
CREATE VIEW vSalesTerritory(SLSTERCD, TerritoryName, Region) AS SELECT SLSTERCD, TerritoryName, Region FROM "SALESTERRITORY";
```

dropping and recreating the view

```
CREATE VIEW vSalesTerritory AS SELECT SLSTERCD, TerritoryName, Region FROM "SALESTERRITORY";
```

solved the problem in LinqPad too.

Comment: Did Windows Update restart your PC and was the DB open while that happened? (just covering basics)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by recreating the view, and removing the column names in the beginning

OLD:
CREATE VIEW vSalesTerritory(SLSTERCD, TerritoryName, Region) AS SELECT SLSTERCD, TerritoryName, Region FROM "SALESTERRITORY";

NEW:
CREATE VIEW vSalesTerritory AS SELECT SLSTERCD, TerritoryName, Region FROM "SALESTERRITORY";